# Virtual machines in Hyper-V appear very sluggish, despite beefy machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, hyper-v, kali-linux, hyper-v-manager

My physical machine has an Intel i9-9900X with 64GB of RAM.  So why can't it seem to smoothly run two virtual machines at the same time.

I am trying to run both Ubuntu and Kali Linux smoothly on the Windows Hyper-V, but both of them are very sluggish to interact with. Tried to assign more/less memory and processors to them without any improvement. My real intention is not to run both at the same time, but to run one at a time, as smoothly as possible.

At this point the settings are to give the Ubuntu VM 8GB of RAM and 4 virtual processors, and the Kali Linux VM is set to 4GB of RAM and 3 virtual processors. Tried with various values of both RAM and processors, and with or without the 'Dynamic Memory' - but without any improvement.. **Does anybody have any idea what will make the VM's perform smoothly?**

Comment: If by "smoothly" you mean 60fps+ GUI interaction, this isn't possible right now as far as I know. Hyper-V uses a modified version of Windows Remote Desktop to facilitate connections to the VMs, and the video you see from the guest OS is limited by that technology.

Comment: If you wish to consider an alternative, I am running both Kali (2020.1) and Ubuntu (18.04) as virtual machines inside VMware Workstation V15.5. Both machines have 1 CPU with 2 Cores and 2GB RAM on a 16 GB Windows 10 host. Both machines run very smoothly and I am in Kali now as I post this.

Comment: I suggest you try a better virtual machine application. I find dual boot (reboot to go the other machine) very limiting.

Comment: @jhermansen Are both virtual machines on the same physical hard disk or SSD?

Comment: @John - Hyper-V is a market leader in virtualization.  There are not a great deal of choices after you decide not to use it.  I don't understand your suggestion.

Comment: If Hyper-V is causing lag issues, it does not matter if they are a numerical leader, my suggestion is to try another product. VMware is working superbly for me.

Comment: @DaveM Yes, on 1TB SSD, which is my second SSD, separated from my host Windows OS on a 250GB SSD. 
Used VMware before, just wanted to try out the built-in Hyper-V manager in Windows Pro instead - but didn't get it to run as smoothly as in VMware.. Decided to go back to VMware for now, at least until it is possible to run VM's without looking like I'm running it at 20-30Hz.

Answer (score 1):

I used to run Kali inside Win7 and Win10 without any performance issues. As already mentioned in comments, Hyper-V RD doesn’t perform the best way in GUI and you can notice some worth experience in compare to host.

For Ubuntu – install and connect with VNC. [Guide](https://hackernoon.com/installation-of-vnc-server-on-ubuntu-1cf035370bd3)

For Kali I’d suggest use simple SSH and work from CLI. If GUI is required, use VNC. Another [guide](https://www.poftut.com/how-to-install-and-access-tightvnc-remote-desktop-in-linux/).

You can also tweak our Hyper-V as described in the following [article](http://www.hyper-v.io/several-tips-hints-full-throttle-hyper-v-performance/).