# Hyper-V sluggish when running PowerShell scripts

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I am running fully patched Windows 10 and have 64 GB RAM and a new AMD Ryzen 5 7600 6-Core CPU. Performance on the host is great. I've setup Hyper-V and creating VM's is fast and snappy.

I have created a single Windows 10 VM with 6 GB of RAM, and inside that, I run a configuration script (written by me, just to setup some apps and changes to the UI that I like in a system), the performance grinds almost to a halt while the script is running (I run this script from an elevated console inside the VM). I see the same behaviour with a single Windows 11 VM. The whole UI moves like a snail. Even just opening another console while this script is running (and the script is not doing anything special, some robocopy jobs, some registry key changes), in that new console, each keypress takes 4-5 seconds to be registered. Inside the script there is an operation `choco install vim -y` which should take about 5 seconds on my Host system, but I can watch the percentage of the download moving like a snail, 1%, 2%, 3%, each percent taking about 4-5 seconds).

I've tried completely rebuilding my Host OS. I've tried completely rebuilding the VMs, but every time, constantly, almost unimaginably bad performance when I run a PowerShell script.

Please, does anyone have any possibly changes that I can make to the configuration as it is really strange to me that the performance is so bad (only when running PowerShell scripts by the way, if I run `choco install vim -y` outside of the script, it runs fine). What causes these VM slowdowns as consistently and as repeatable as this?

Linking to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1526659/virtual-machines-in-hyper-v-appear-very-sluggish-despite-beefy-machine) post, but the problem there seems to be about multiple VM's; I get this sluggish performance with a single VM.

Comment: Does it still happen if you minimize the console window that's generating the output?

Comment: How many processors has the VM been given? Is anything CPU intensive being done on the host when the script is running on the client VM? Are other VMs running when this occurs? Does the host have plenty of free memory available if Dynamic Memory is enabled on the client VM?

Comment: On what disk is the VM running? An SSD or HDD?

Comment: Always SSD (system only has 2x NVMe and no other disks), 1 vCPU (maybe this is the problem, I'm experimenting after the point from @JW9014 (though I would have thought that 1 vCPU should be plenty for basic operation). I don't really know how to optimise Hyper-V VMs though so am working through these suggestions. I'm also going to try minimising (or closing) the `vmconnect` window as suggested above also.

Comment: Hyper-V changes (updates) with OS Updates.  You said machine is new - try upgrading to Windows 11 Pro and see. Nothing lost so far as I can see. I have Hyper-V on Windows 11 and VMs are fast.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, these were a great help. It looks like it was to do with having 1 vCPU. I am applying the following settings I've found on optimising VMs so they operate very fast now: `Set-VM -Name $vmName -DynamicMemory`, `Set-VMProcessor -VMName $vmName -Count 4`, `Enable-VMIntegrationService -VMName $vmName -Name "Guest Service Interface"`, `Set-VMNetworkAdapter -VMName $vmName -Name "Network Adapter" -VmqWeight 100 -VmmqEnabled 100`